# Is it possible to "delay" payments with push-based synchronous/asynchronous method of payments?

Tags: payment

I'm looking for a way to charge my customer after a request was successfully accepted.

To explain it further. I'm developing a marketplace where a **private seller** can sell his products to **private customers**. But the customer can only "request" the product and only when the seller accepts his conditions a deal is made.

Now comes the question that I have. Is it possible that the user is paying for the request but is only charged when the request is accepted?

If a request fails the charge has never been done or gets a full refund (but without the loss of transactions fees).

I've seen some couple of websites that use credit cards for that case. 
If you look at credit cards as a payment method they are usually a pull-based, reusable and synchronous method of payment. This means that, after capturing the customer’s card details, you can debit arbitrary amounts from the customer’s card without them having to take any additional action and there is immediate confirmation about the success or failure of a payment.

So that is why you can charge someone after a specific period of time.

But in Germany, we don't use credit cards that often. Only pushed-based transactions like Sepa/Sofort/iDeal. Would it be possible to "delay" payments with these methods?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. I'm not sure what payment processor you are using/want to use or what is available in Germany but I assume this would be possible with many of them. Probably some useful things to search for that might be similar to what you want would be saving payment methods for later, managing subscriptions, and tokenizing credit cards.

**Stripe** for example allows you to save credit cards for later under a customer record and then charge a customer later. https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards

**Braintree** has recurring billing https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/overview and a vault for storing payment methods https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview.

Comment: Well the link for "saving-cards" is only good for pull-based methods. If you use iDeal/Sofort I think it's just not possible because it's a one time payment at the very moment where you need to give your bank data. But thank you anyways it helped me a bit.

Comment: Hmm ya I'm not familiar with those providers. Are you using push-based to refer to transactions that happen immediately? I'm not familiar with that terminology. It seems like some provider should be able to save bank account details for later or do recurring payments but idk what's available in your country. We save bank payment methods and have recurring payments but I'm not familiar with how we process those in the backend. It's some enterprise solution.